# Power BI Report Builder claiming I don't have permissions I do have

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, permission-denied, reportbuilder3.0, power-bi-report-server

I am updating a Power BI Report Builder report for 2024. I made the report, it uses data sources I have access to on a daily basis, and that I used to create that same report. When I try to run it, I get this error:

### `Error: Either the user, 'myuserid@email.com', does not have permission to access the referenced mining model, 'Power BI Report Data Source', or the object does not exist.
Error: Either the user, 'myuserid@email.com', does not have permission to access the referenced mining model, 'Power BI Report Data Source', or the object does not exist.

### Query execution failed for dataset 'Years'.

### An error has occurred during report processing.

`An error occurred during local report processing.`
`

Any idea what the problem could be, how I could work around this?

I've already rebooted. When I go into Dataset Properties, I get the same error when I attempt to validate query.

When I go into Query Designer, the query definition that was showing in dataset properties is gone. However, I *can* navigate to the dataset, Years datasource column, and actually see all the members.

The query I'm using is:
`SELECT DISTINCT([Power BI Report Data Source].[Report Year]) FROM [Power BI Report Data Source]`

The headline of the error I get when validating is "Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct." The query syntax has not changed in the since I last updated the report 2 months ago.

Any ideas?